# How HTML meta charset works

Tags: html, character-encoding

How does meta charset work? Please correct my understanding if I am wrong. As I understand it, the charset is used as to indicate what encoding the page is to be shown? If I put a very specific encoding, others might not be able to see it displayed correctly. But why? Isn't the encoding set on the meta tage and the browser renders characters based on the charset? Or do I have the wrong idea (probably)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letters, numbers and other characters have to represented in computers as bytes.

There are different ways (character encodings) that can be used to represent the same characters. Usually you'll want to use UTF-8 these days.

Meta charset tells the browser which one you have used so it knows how to decode the bytes into characters correctly.

If you tell the browser you are using UTF-8 when you are actually using ISO-8859-1, then you'll get errors (the wrong characters) showing up in places where the encodings do not overlap.

Comment: Wait, the last part of what you typed is what is confusing for me. "If you tell the browser you are using UTF-8 when you are actually using ISO-8859-1". I thought what is displayed is what you specify in meta tag (the UTF-8). So wherever the page is displayed, it will be encoded in UTF-8. This statement "when you are actually using ISO-8859-1", what does it mean? My setting in the operating system?

Comment: He is saying that if a document *says* it's encoded one way, but is *actually* encoded a different way, the characters may not render correctly.

The simplified priority for determining document encoding (in browser) is: (1) browser setting, (2) byte order mark (browser is able to determine encoding on its own), (3) HTTP header, (4) meta tag, (5) best guess.

Comment: @g_b — The encoding is determined by your *editor* when you save the file. Meta is (one thing) used by the *browser* to determine how to *decode* the file.

Comment: There is still a bit of confusion for me. I typed some Chinese character in VS2013 with meta tag charset UTF-8 and it showed properly. I then saved the file as Chinese traditional (big5) encoding and then it showed gibberish. I changed the charset meta tag to also big5 and expected it to show correctly but it didn't? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Probably something else (see the list in Ben's previous comment) is setting UTF-8 before meta is.

Answer (score 1):

**character_set** Specifies the character encoding for the HTML document.

In theory, any character encoding can be used, but no browser understands all of them. The more widely a character encoding is used, the better the chance that a browser will understand it.