# Priority charset detection in web browser

Tags: html, character-encoding, http-headers, w3c, byte-order-mark

I really need to know the priority of processing of encoding indication in web browser(HTML5). Answer please with sources please.

1. Http header
2. BOM
3. Meta
4. Heuristic / user setting

I dont know the number of BOM(somewhere second[https://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-character-encoding], somewhere first[[How HTML meta charset works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784550/how-html-meta-charset-works])). I dont know when browser detects according to user setting a when with heuristic method.

Sources: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2 , http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#character-encoding , http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset

Big thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BOM should go before the HTTP header. <sup>[1][2]</sup>

There are many official [documents](https://www.w3.org/blog/2008/03/html-charset/) [that](http://nikitathespider.com/articles/EncodingDivination.html) [say](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#charset) HTTP header goes before the BOM.  [Apparently](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/apps-discuss/current/msg10514.html), we are to ignore them and reverse the order such that latter has higher precedence.

**Therefore:**

1. BOM
2. HTTP Header `Content-Type:`
3. `<meta>` / `@charset` for css
4. Environment (`charset` attribute of parent `<iframe>` and `<link>` elements, encoding of parent document, etc) and/or heuristics

I'm not quite sure (haven't really looked into) the precedence within `4.`.  Also, <sup>[1]</sup> puts "user setting" before BOM.

<sup>[1]</sup> *Note: That this step happens before the next one honoring the HTTP Content-Type header is a willful violation of the HTTP specification, motivated by a desire to be maximally compatible with legacy content.* --
 https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding

<sup>[2]</sup> *Note: The decode algorithm gives precedence to a byte order mark (BOM), and only uses the fallback when none is found.* -- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#input-byte-stream

Comment: "User setting" before BOM sounds pretty crazy :)